# AS3 flashing dynamically appending movieclip names to goto functions

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, types

I have a virtual on screen keyboard for a touch screen interface.
I get the name of the key (Q, W, E, etc) by calling event.currentTarget.name
Now each button is a movie clip with a small animation and I need to know
which key is pressed so it can call the relevent movieclip..
Below is the code:

```
function keyPressed(event:MouseEvent):void {

    var butID:String = event.currentTarget.name;
    trace("clicked " + butID);

 //////////////ERROR BELOW///////////

    Q.gotoAndPlay(2); <-------- Q is the name of the movieclip. It has to be something like butID.gotoAndPlay(2); but it doesn't work. I'm not sure of the type of the variable either...Can any one help?

/////////////////////////////
//Below I append the letter to a text box
    if(event.currentTarget.name == "SPACE")
    {
        addText(" ");
    }
    else
    {
        addText(event.currentTarget.name);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Luben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay(2);` ?

Comment: Thanks a mill!! I was trying event.currentTarget.name.gotoAndPlay(2); which wasn't working.